# What's longer than an hour and shorter than a minute?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

What's longer than an hour and shorter than a minute?

The puzzle is NOT about counting letters in a word (h/t @Carl)

To verify your answer, or to help to answer, you can use the following hints:

> Hint 1: The subject of the puzzle is atypical of its kind.
>  Hint 2: It may have been valued at 800.

Comment: I'd recommend turning those hints into part of the puzzle ( as to constrain the answer ).  Right now, it's too broad because any five letter word fits.

Comment: okay, but such is the nature of the site.  People would rather have something "too easy" than play a guessing game.  I actually don't know the answer with the hints, so I guess I'm not that bright.

Comment: is it 800 or 0800 (as in time - o eight hundred)

Comment: @smriti - 800. SE isn't Microsoft Excel, to eat leading zeros :)

Comment: I thought it might be a candle, as sometimes they are measured in hours (burning time) and it could be quite small, i.e. minute as in very small but then it doesn't fit the second hint.

Comment: @RadoslavHristov Another example why restrictions/hints are so necessary in this type of puzzles. Without:too broad and bad puzzle. With (enough and good) conditions: interesting challenge

Comment: Talking for 59 seconds with someone that REALLY likes underground music and fashion design

Comment: Is it always the case or is it either this( longer than an hour ) or that(less long than a minute)

Answer (score 6):

Is it...

> Hands on a clock face
>  The minute hand is longer than the hour hand and the hour hand is 'less longer' than a minute hand

Comment: sounds possible, but how does your answer fit the hints?

Comment: I can't provide a solid justification when it comes to explaining the hints

Comment: Close but not quite right

Comment: So second hand, in most cases longer than hour hand and slightly shorter than minute one.

Answer (score 3):

Before I read the hints, I was sure the answer was:

> a [tachyon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon) - because as a particle that travels faster than the speed of light, it effectively travels backwards in time, and so would view an hour as less than a minute.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was a

> a 30 sencond Hourglass timer.

Because the

> word itself is more than an hour

and

> it measures less than a minute.

But hints make me unsure :(

> anyway 8 may refer to the shape of an hourglass.

Comment: 1. I explicitly said that it wasn't about character counting. 2. Even absent that, hourglass is longer than a minute by character count.